# In Python, can I hide a base class's members?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am making a programming framework (based on Django) that is intended for students with limited programming experience. Students are supposed to inherit from my base classes (which themselves are inherited from Django models, forms, and views).

I am testing this out now with some students, and the problem is that when they write code in their IDE (most of them are using PyCharm), autocomplete gives them a ton of suggestions, since there are so many inherited methods and attributes, 90% of which are not relevant to them.

Is there some way to hide these inherited members? At the moment I am primarily thinking of how to hide them in auto-complete (in PyCharm and other IDEs). They can (and probably should) still work if called, but just not show up in places like auto-complete.

I tried setting `__dict__`, but that did not affect what showed up in autocomplete. Another idea I have is to use composition instead of inheritance, though I would have to think this through in more detail.

**Edit**: This framework is not being used in CS classes; rather, students will be using it to build apps for non-CS domain. So my priority is to keep it simple as possible, perhaps even if it's not a "pure" approach. (Nevertheless, I am considering those arguments as they do have merit.)

Comment: I would imagine there is nothing you can do to hide something from autocomplete, and yet have it still callable. If there *is* something you can do, it would have to be via the IDE (some kind of configuration), not via your Python code. Python is not IDE-aware. It doesn't control how your IDE (or editor or whatever) behaves.

Comment: Is making your students _that_dependent of an IDE or even autocompletion in particular any healthy?

Comment: I think the correct solution is to [teach your students python's naming conventions](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) (and make sure your code follows them). Options in autocomplete are in alphabetical order, and the ``'_'`` character comes later in the alphabet than ``'a'->'Z'``, so if you follow the naming conventions your public API should be first in the autocomplete list. Following that standard is a lesson they're going to need to learn anyway, So I wouldn't try and hide it from them.

Comment: Consider the other consequences of just hiding the base class API rather than actually abstracting it away: What if a student, not knowing that a method name is already used by a base-class (because it doesn't show up in autocomplete, or the documentation you've provided), decides to name one of their own methods that and winds up completely breaking everything because they overrode a method without realizing it?

Comment: Hmm... while Python doesn't affect how the IDE behaves *per se*, it looks like @ThomasOrozco's clever way shows you can *exploit* the IDE's limitations within your Python code.

Comment: @aruisdante: You bring up good points. You may want to consider turning your two lengthy comments into an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Disclaimer: the following method isn't very clean** (but that's what you're asking for).

Now, the good news is that this method will **never break your Python**. In fact, it will only affect the IDE.

However, note that PyCharm may become smarter in the future, and get autocomplete to work anyway. I don't think this would be a priority for the Jetbrains team, though!

---

Here we go.

All you have to do is confuse PyCharm a bit. PyCharm won't be able to reliably follow imports performed using `__import__`, so we'll use that to import your django modules (if PyCharm doesn't which module you're importing, it can't know which class you are using and which methods to present in the autocomplete window!).

In the following example, we'll assume that:

- `_base.py` is the django file that contains the class you want to extend (and whose methods you want to hide)
- `base.py` is the file that contains the class you want to provide your students with (whose methods you want to show)
- `test.py` is the file that your students will write

### `_base.py`

Nothing in particular here

```
class DjangoBaseClass(object):
    def method_that_is_hidden(self):
        print "The hidden method is there!"
```

### `base.py`

Note the import

```
base = __import__("_base")  # This is equivalent to `import base`. Python understands it, but PyCharm doesn't.

class YourBaseClass(base.DjangoBaseClass):  # PyCharm doesn't know what class this is! No autocomplete.
    def method_that_shows(self):
        print "The method that shows is there!"
```

**Important note:** in the case of a multi-level import, the syntax is a bit different. For example, to inherit from `django.views.generic.base.View`, do:

```
base = __import('django.views.generic.base', fromlist=['View',])

class MyView(base.View):
    # Your stuff
```

Note that if PyCharm gets smarter in the future, you'll have to add some more indirection (e.g. instead of `__import__('base')`, you could use `__import__(''.join(['b', 'a', 's', 'e']))`. This will get messy, though.

### `test.py`

Nothing in particular here

```
from base import YourBaseClass

class StudentClass(YourBaseClass):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = StudentClass()
    c.method_that_is_hidden()
    c.method_that_shows()
```

When you run the `test.py` script, the methods both work:

```
$ python test.py
The hidden method is there!
The method that shows is there!
```

But when you use PyCharm, `method_that_is_hidden` does not show up in autocomplete:

[image: the hidden method does not show]

---

Note: I believe PyCharm now has features to follow call trees when you run tests, so if your students run tests using PyCharm, PyCharm may pick up the existence of those methods. I suppose they won't show in class definitions, but they may show if your students write `c.`. You should try it and see for yourself.

Comment: While this would work, it's a pretty horrific hack that teaches any student that looks at the base code some pretty terrible practices. The correct answer is to teach them how to distinguish between a public and private API and how to read documentation, not to write bad  python to hack PyCharm to hide methods from autocomplete.

Comment: @aruisdante I'm suspecting the author doesn't want his students using Django's public APIs in the first place. While I agree this is a hack, we have to realize that it may not be possible to teach the students everything at once, and thus relying on a couple hacks to hide complexity at first can be reasonable.

Comment: @ThomasOrozoco Sure, but those API's are still there, and hiding them without actually disabling them seems like a terrible idea. Why not teach them how to read documentation and only document your public API? I'm all for hiding functionality to improve simplicity if the functionality is actually abstracted away, but essentially making it 'undocumented' but there isn't really doing that. What if a student accidentally overrides a method that they didn't know was a method in a base class because it was hidden from them?

Comment: @aruisdante Note that the only thing we are disabling really is the IDE's autocomplete here. We're not "hiding" them from the Python code. IDEs will sometimes fail: while `import` is naturally preferred to `__import__`, there's a fair amount of reasonable use cases for the latter, which will break the IDE's autocomplete. Now, this is really a baseless discussion anyway: we don't know the use case the teacher has for this. Just providing the tools. That's all.

Comment: @aruisdante As to whether this is "horrific", we could achieve the same using `globals()["DjangoBaseClass"]` — now *that* would be horrific ;)

Comment: Ha ha I mean that's what you have to do sometimes to run ``eval``, although hopefully you're copying ``globals``, not appending directly to it. Depending on how PyCharm does its autocomplete indexing, it would be pretty trivial to detect the ``__import__`` method and simply evaluate the code inside the ``()`` to determine what is being imported, since it always needs to be a string ;)

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I used `importlib.import_module`, which is a wrapper around `__import__`. Looks like a great solution!

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you to use composition instead of inheritance. Then you design class's interface and decide which methods are available.

Comment: Composition won't be that easy to implement for Django specific classes.

Comment: I know. But it is the only way to exclude some methods from derived class

Answer (score -2):

I think the correct solution is to [teach your students python's naming conventions](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) (and make sure your code follows them). Options in autocomplete are in alphabetical order, and the `'_'` character comes later in the alphabet than `'a'->'Z'`, so if you follow the naming conventions your public API should be first in the autocomplete list. Following that standard is a lesson they're going to need to learn anyway, So I wouldn't try and hide it from them.

Now I can understand why you might want to hide Django's public API from them, but consider the other consequences of just hiding the base class API rather than actually abstracting it away: What if a student, not knowing that a method name is already used by a base-class (because it doesn't show up in autocomplete, or the documentation you've provided), decides to name one of their own methods that and winds up completely breaking everything because they overrode a method without realizing it?

Basically, you're trying to hide what's actually in the class from the students rather than teaching them the information they need to know to not do things they shouldn't. This almost always results in simply increasing the likelihood of things going wrong. It's also teaching them to be completely dependent on the features of their IDE; E.X. if it's not in autocomplete, it must not exist!

I think you need to look at the root causes of the concerns you have, and attempt to create lessons that address those concerns, rather than figure out hacks that work around them and potentially teach your students back programming practices. Learning how to read documentation properly is a really, REALLY important part of being a programer. Don't try and make them not have to learn that lesson. Hell, not learning that lesson is what results in 99% of questions (especially on Python for whatever reason) on Stack Exchange.